# problem when we add debian 6.0 to my domain (windows server 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008

i installed debian 6.0 ,i need to add it to my domain (windows machine) i used this link to do that
http://zeldor.biz/2010/12/debian-join-windows-domain/
but when i tried to synchronize my clock with the primary domain controller, i got this error
 "no server suitable for synchronization found"

can anyone tell me where is the problem

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the ntp client cannot find a suitable server to talk to (am I sounding like a parrot?).
So have a look at your /etc/ntp.conf file. It must either contain a line pointing at your domain controller, like this:

```
server <dc-host-name>.<your>.<domain>
```

or you should use the default configuration:

```
server 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

Which will, obviously, only work if you can reach these servers through your firewall.
You might want to use nmap to see whether the relevant ports are open on the configured servers (NTP uses port 123).